# Nested DIV elements

Tags: css, xhtml, html

I am trying to enclose two DIV elements, inner-1 & inner-2, (dotted red border) inside a wrapper DIV (solid green border) but the wrapper DIV element does not expand to enclose the inner DIVs.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> Nested divs </title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border:solid #669933;"> 
  content inside "wrapper" div
  <div id="inner-1" style="float:left; width:49%; border:dotted #CC3300;">
    content <br />
    inside <br />
    inner-1 div
  </div>

  <div id="inner-2" style="float:left; width:49%; border:dotted #CC3300;"> 
    content inside inner-2 div 
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Rendered HTML](http://i42.tinypic.com/dcwp35.png)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since you're floating both `#inner-1` and `#inner-2`, you'll need a [clear fix](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/02/26/simple-clearing-of-floats/). Basically, setting `overflow: auto` on the parent (`#wrapper`) should do the trick.

Comment: setting 'width:100%' and 'overflow:hidden' also works for parent element

Comment: Is there really no other solution than to use Javascript? I'm having the same problem, the outer div has no solid width, but using Javascript seems a workaround.

Comment: The link to the clear fix in the post above has moved to [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/simple-clearing-of-floats/)

Answer (score 4):

```
.
.
.
 <div id="inner-2" style="float:left; width:49%; border:dotted #CC3300;"> 
     content inside inner-2 div 
 </div>
 <br style="clear:both" />
</div>
.
.
.
```

Try that.

You can set the margins for the `<br />` so that it is hardly visible too.

Answer (score 3):

It is the floats that are giving you the problem.
this might work for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> Nested divs </title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border:solid #669933;"> 
  content inside "wrapper" div
  <div id="inner-1" style="float:left; width:49%; border:dotted #CC3300;">
    content <br />
    inside <br />
    inner-1 div
  </div>

  <div id="inner-2" style="float:left; width:49%; border:dotted #CC3300;"> 
    content inside inner-2 div 
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Added "div style="clear: both">" at the bottom of the containing DIV.

Answer (score 2):

It might also be worth noting that there are a few different methods of "clearing floats" out there.  This one works pretty well for me and only involves adding a single class to the parent element:

```
.clearfix:after{content:"\0020";display:block;height:0;clear:both;
 visibility:hidden;overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 2):

As has been said already you need some method of forcing the containing div to realize the floating divs have taken up space.  Commonly known as clearing a float, there are quite a few discussions on the topic around the internet.

[This post](http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2007/09/developers-note-2/) at pathf.com is one of the more popular to use. When you read the article be sure to read all the comments as well.