# Putting borders on <div>s within another <div>

Tags: css

I've got several `<div>`s inside another `<div>`, and they fit just right, but I would like to add a border to distinguish between them. However, when I add a border or an outline, it shows surrounding the outside of the div. Is there a way to get it so that the border will be inside the edge of the div?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5cSke/11/

I would like the inner `<div>`s to all stay within the outer div, and for the borders not to expand and cover anything outside the inner `<div>`s.

**EDIT (Partial Solution):** I was able to find a partial solution by setting the overflow of the containing div to hidden, which prevented the borders from spreading beyond the outer `<div>`, but not from spreading between the `<div>`s within it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's how the [box model](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-sizing/) works. There is a CSS3 `box-sizing: border-box` style that will let you do what you want.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5cSke/14/

Answer (score 2):

you can make several divs within each other just give specify style for each one using
div id or class

```
<style>
    div {
    border : 2px solid red;
    }

    div #test2 {
    border : 1px solid black;
    }
</style>

<div id="test1">
main div
    <div id="test2">inner div</div>
 <br>
</div>
```

for more information

[Nested DIV elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087602/nested-div-elements)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to prevent the border from appearing on the outside of your divs. I would instead recommend setting background colours on your divs in order to distinguish between them.

Comment: I considered that, but there could be an arbitrary number of inner divs, and there are only so many color options...

Answer (score 0):

There might be a new css 3 property to do stuff like that. But there is a more elegant solution. Give each div an rgba value with some opacity. Overlapping (or) nested divs will have a darker background then its parent.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pnkgH/)

Comment: I like it, but it doesn't really accomplish what I'm trying to do, which is add borders to the nested divs to distinguish between them without expanding/overlapping anything. (I would just space them out, but space is very tight in this case and that is not a viable option)

Comment: If space is tight would the different colour backgrounds, as @Sebastian Motraghi suggested not be spot on? :)

Comment: Inbreed @frostbite however you'll need a distinctive rule for every div. What if he has 20 nested divs? Mine will use one rule for all divs. You can adjust it as needed.